# Unable recieve IPN for Dynamic DNS with Port forwarding in Paypal sandbox Environment

Tags: paypal-ipn

I have 'Seller Account' in Paypal sandbox environment and I configured the URL for listening the IPN messages from Paypal API.  My Web server uses Dynamic DNS with Port forwarding.  But I cannot get any notification messages from Paypal API while doing the payments.  Is Paypal sandbox environment does not support for Dynamic DNS servers with Port forwarding?. And is there any configuration setting need to be done for receiving IPN notifications in Dynamic DNS server.  Can anyone helped me to solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PayPal's IPN service requires a HTTP/1.1 200 OK response and ideally connect on port 80 (HTTP) or 443 (HTTPS). Anything else is bound to run into issues.

Comment: Thank you Robert I spend lot of time to fix this.  My IPN handler was listening on Port 5555.  Now I changed to 80 through proxy pass.  It working fine.  Sorry for the delay...

Comment: This is a pain for every developers. Couldn't PayPal allow other ports too just for sandbox?

Answer (score 1):

Use a service like IPN Relay http://ipnrelay.com/
It collects your IPNs for you and lets you collect them from within your LAN and redistribute them to your dev box just as if they came directly from PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting blocked by a firewall along the way.  Make sure that you are able to receive inbound connections by checking FW logs and enabling inbound filters (or port redirection).

Alternately you can also try a different DDNS provider - try a free account maybe?  Some listed here: http://dnslookup.me/dynamic-dns/